# Compiling Accept API/Framework with Visual Studio Namespace error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, build, compilation, namespaces

I am trying to compile a project with Visual Studio 2013 (https://github.com/accept-project/accept-portal to see the details), but after following all the instructions and solving all dependencies problems, I always got a Namespace error when building the solution.

The code is not from me and my knowledge in C# is close to none.

What I would like to know is: can the namespace errors come from a mistake on my side or is it an actual error from the code itself?

[image]

Any help would be higly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Simon

Comment: The documentation on that project is pretty much giving you step by step instructions. If you did it correctly and still does not work, contact the project owner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I did contact him but he's very busy at the moment so I wanted to be sure that those errors are not coming from me since it's the first time I'm doing this ^^